# How to fix "XML parsing error: incomprehensible data after the document element"?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, wordpress

I work locally on WAMP and the JS doesn't work. When I click on a button, I get this error in the console.

I've searched the Internet a lot without finding an answer.

Here is the console error :

```
XML parsing error: incomprehensible data after the document element
Location : http://.../index.php
Line number 2, column
```

Here is the code  index.php:2:1

```
<?php
include('./header.php');
if ($_POST){
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='$password'");
```

I'd like the JS to work.

Do you have a solution?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: `mysql_` functions were *deprecated* in **php5** and removed in **php7**

Comment: also checking $_POST is a false positive, someone could post a key with foo, and your code will still try to execute the sql, even if `$_POST['password']` isn't set

Comment: Thank you for your answers, unfortunately, the problem is still not solved.